# How to manage Chrome sync data? (Like delete something?)

Tags: google-chrome, sync, google-chrome-extensions, google-sync

I've got one problem with Chrome sync: I can't delete anything. It's like... merging everything from the past, to the latest minute. Everything.

If I delete the applications I've tried (like offline GMail), it'll install them on the other PC too. (Or if I remove Chrome and re-sync).

**Is there a way to remove something from the Chrome sync?**
(Except erasing *everything*... I don't really want to start saving my passwords and stuff again.)

Comment: I guess chrome team didn't resolve any conflict in sync. That's why this is happening.

Comment: I am having the same issue with Chrome sync. I have a homepage tab that I set that I can no longer get rid of (unless I manually remove it on each computer i set up sync on). What needs to happen is when something is removed it has to be removed from the "repository" also.

Comment: You can browse through that data at chrome://sync-internals/ and you will find ID's there. There is probably some (undocumented) function to delete entry by an ID from a background page process.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve my issues by cleaning up the settings on one "master" chrome instance, setting everything the way I wanted it to be. Then, I went to Google Dashboard and cleared all Chrome Sync data from there. It takes a few minutes, refresh until it says everything is empty ("Nothing to see here"), go ahead and sign in to sync on Chrome. Now everything should be good. Just try not to add stuff you dont want from now on, like syncing to your account on an instance of Chrome which has a bunch of settings you do not want.

Comment: That is quite inconvenient. Thanks for the help, though. Guess I'll do this while there is no easier way.

Comment: It's not too much work, and it allows you to have full control rather than worrying about if certain delete operations got registered and such.

Comment: @StevenLu - 1. Did you first "sign out" from Google account on this "Master" Chrome instance - before doing the RESET/ Clear on Google Dashboard? 2. Also, did you sign out of other "slave" Chrome instances. 

Please update steps and clarify in the answer

Answer (score 1):

To delete sync data from chrome is easy you have to actually Delete sync data from Google Dashboard.

Just go [here](https://www.google.com/dashboard/b/0/?hl=en_GB) and delete sync data. this might take a some time.

Try to sync again, login again in chrome with your google data

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/sync

Answer (score 0):

if you hit the configuration-wrench, then options, then private you will see a section concerning login, if you hit 'Extended' or 'Advanced' (i dont use the english version) in that section you will get a small window where you can select which data shall be synchronized.

that 'should' help. you might have to do that on all machines that are connected to your google-account, i am not sure about that. play around a bit.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to keep _everything_ sync-ed. By sync, I don't want deleted content re-appearing. It's really annoying, to have about 10apps installed again, and again after every re-sync.